# how to escape \ in received json fields

Tags: json, playframework-2.6

My application receives a `json` in Http response

```
 {"result":"success","additional-info":"{\"external-profile\":{\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"firstname\":\"ln\",\"lastname\":\"fn\",\"password\":\"somePassword\"}}"}
```

I have written a `reads` to convert incoming message into a `case class`

```
implicit val externalProfileAPIReads:Reads[ExternalUserProfileAPI] = (
    (JsPath \ "external-profile").read[ExternalUserProfile]
    ).map((x:ExternalUserProfile)=>(ExternalUserProfileAPI.apply(x)))
```

But in my unit tests, when I try to convert the message, the conversion fails.

```
val message = (responseBody \ "additional-info").get.as[ExternalUserProfileAPI]
```

The error is

```
JsResultException(errors:List((/external-profile,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray())))))
play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((/external-profile,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray())))))
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable.$anonfun$as$2(JsReadable.scala:25)
```

Question 1- Is the conversion failing because the `json` fields in the received message has `\` in it?

Question 2- In the "method under test", I am not explicitly adding the `\`s in the response. I just call `toString()` on a `case class` when sending the response. `Json.toJson(externalProfileAPI).toString()`. If `\` is the issue, how can I either not send them in the sent response or escape them at the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: Is the conversion failing because the json fields in the
>   received message has `\` in it?

Yes, because the string at its current state is not proper Json, you have to remove (escape) those backslashes.

> Question 2: If `\` is the issue, how can I either not send them in the
>   sent response or escape them at the client side?

Did you by any chance call `JSON.stringify()` on the json on the sending end? If so, removing it will remove the backslashes. Otherwise, you can call `JSON.parse(YOUR_STRING)` to escape the backslashes on the receiving end.

Comment: At the sending side, I call `val result:Future[AuthenticatorResult] = silhouette.env.authenticatorService.embed(securityToken, Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess(Json.toJson(externalProfileAPI).toString()))))`. I don't know if that adds the "\". At the receive side, I tried `val responseBody:String = contentAsString(resultFuture);
      println(s"received result ${responseBody}");
      val responsBodyAsJson = Json.parse(responseBody);
      println(s"received result as json${responsBodyAsJson}");`
      ` but I stil get the "\"

Comment: I just realized that you actually have a "stringfied" JSON inside a JSON, in that case, simply using `JSON.parse` will not help. Do you have to nest the Json inside, it might be easier if you don't, but if you have to nest it in there, extract that Json sub element out and call `JSON.parse` on it should work.

Comment: Thanks. So `val responseBody = contentAsJson(resultFuture) //responseBody has backslashes` then `val message:String = (responseBody \ "additional-info").get.as[String] //removes the backslashes` and finally `val userProfile = Json.parse(message)`

Comment: Glad I could help, please consider upvote if my answer has helped you.